# Using switch inside seek bar in android: can't detect initial value

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am using a seekbar for showing 4 validity(1 Day,7 Days,15 days, 30days) of a product in android studio using switch cases. Problem is initially it starts from 0. But once I slide to any other value and then if I slide back to initial value it does not show the initial value. Instead it shows the 1st value (7 Days). I am new to android. Pardon me if it is a repetition.

```js
    SeekBar seekBarVl;
    TextView textViewVl;

......

seekBarVl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
           public int progressVl =0;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progressVl= progress;

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            )

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                switch (progressVl) {
                    case 0:
                        Vl = 1;
                        textViewVl.setText("Validity: " + Vl+" Days");


                    case 1:
                        Vl = 7;
                        textViewVl.setText("Validity: " + Vl+" Days");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Vl = 15;
                        textViewVl.setText("Validity: " + Vl+" Days");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Vl = 30;
                        textViewVl.setText("Validity: " + Vl+" Days");
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need add a "break" after first "case" ;-)

```
case 0:
         Vl = 1;
         textViewVl.setText("Validity: " + Vl+" Days");
         break;
```

Comment: This was embarrassing !! Thanks buddy !